# python webhook, incoming gzip data - write to file

Tags: python, api, binary, webhooks, raw-data

quite new with python, did some practice and now trying to play with APIs and webhoks.

My goal: I have a network management system that every 120 seconds can send me location data based on WiFi visibility of nearby clients

I wrote this simple code and get incoming data - data are gzipped so I see them in binary

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    print(request.headers)
    print(request.data)
 
    return ('This is a website. Port 443 - Https. ', 200, None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True, ssl_context='adhoc', port=443)
```

Result is:

Host: e7145a924eea.eu.ngrok.io
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_251
Content-Length: 1940
Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/x-jackson-smile, application/cbor, application/*+json, */*
Authorization: Basic 11223344
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
X-Ah-Event-Type: LOCATION
X-Ah-Message-Type: LOCATION_CLIENT_CENTRIC
X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Accept-Encoding: gzip

b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xed\x9cYO\x1bI\x10\x80\xff\xcb<\x93Q\x1fU}\xf8\xad\xaf\xd1"\xe5\x90V<m\x14E^\xf0&H\x04\x10Gv\xa3\x88\xff\xbe5v\x886Am\x9c\xb6{`\x1b\xa4(\x1a\x18\xe39\xbe\xba\xab\xba\xbfv\x9f\x16\x97\x97\xf3\x0f\x8bW\x8b\xaby\x9c_\xcd\xbb\xd9\xd7n\xf1yqzu\xf0\xe5|\xd1\xcd\xba\x97o\x82;\xd8\x7f\xf3\xba\xdb\xbb\xfd\xe4O'\xde\x87\x97\xfb\xe9\xf5\xc1\xfb@\xff\xfd\xbe\x1f\xba\x9b\xbd\xee\xe8\xdb\xf7\x9c\xfd}\xba\xb8\xd8?...omissis...\x99Tqo\xe8\x91pi<N\xab(\x036pPRq\x97\\xe9\xba\xadG"\x03\xd3\xd7\xd5\xf5\x84>z\xa7\xfb6\xbf\xbb\xb9\xf9\x17\x91>x\xad\xfbt\x00\x00'

I simply would like to wirte the binary stream to a file, but if I try to do something like

```
with open("D:\\Dati\python\\200_WebApps_and_webhooks\\API.gzip",'wb') as API_data:
        print(request.data, file=API_data)
```

I got the error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

The idea is to send the raw incoming data to a file that can be unzipped to see the json format.

Next step will be unzipping on the fly and process to print in a format like this

......"bodyRaw":"{"messageMetaData":{"eventType":"LOCATION","messageType":"LOCATION_CLIENT_CENTRIC"},"data":{"ownerId":136502,"observations":[{"clientMac":"aaabbbcccddd","ipv4":null,"ipv6":null,"seenTime":"2021-01-08T16:43:25.154Z","seenEpoch":1610124205154,"userName":null,"authMethod":null,"ssid":null,"manufacturer":null,"os":null,"lat":0.0,"lng":0.0,"x":2.916691159714196,"y":1.9132701186769128,"clientMetaData":null,"deviceObservers":[{"apMac":"885BDD8B3E40","rssi":-74,"locationIdHierarchy":[586271625939276,586271625939269,586271625939267]}]},{"clientMac":"7825AD1136FC","ipv4":null,"ipv6":null,"seenTime":"2021-01-08T16:43:25.163Z","seenEpoch":1610124205163,"userName":null,"authMethod":null,"ssid":null,"manufacturer":null,"os":null,"lat":0.0,"lng":0.0,"x":13.302300953114472,"y":8.587561374795419,"clientMetaData":null,"deviceObservers":[{"apMac":"885BDD8B3E40","rssi":-87,"locationIdHierarchy":[586271625939276,586271625939269,586271625939267]}   ...omissis..

Thanks in advance

Franco

Answer (score 0):

Within your `with` block, the `print` statement doesn't work as you expect it to.  It is for printing stuff to the server console.

I think you're looking for something like:

```
with open("D:\\Dati\python\\200_WebApps_and_webhooks\\API.gzip",'wb') as API_data:
    API_data.write(request.data)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works of course. What would you suggest to decode data "on the fly" as they come from the API source every 120 secs ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the gzip.open() to open .gz files and not 'open'

```py
import gzip
with gzip.open(filepath,"rt") as API_data: # Unzipping and opening the file in text format
    for line in API_data:
        print(line) # Printing each line, you can save these lines to a file if you would like
```

Answer (score 0):

THanks for your hints, I sorted this out using both and writing this sample code

```
from flask import Flask, request
import gzip

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    """
    Go to https://localhost to see a message
    """

    data = request.data
    print("data -> ", data)

    plaindata = gzip.decompress(data)
    print("decomp data ", plaindata)    

    return ('This is a website. Port 443 - Https. ', 200, None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True, ssl_context='adhoc', port=443)
```

Output is

data ->  b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xed[\xdbN\xe3H\x10\xfd\x17?g\xac\xbeWu\xde\xecv\xb7\x16i\x06\xa4\x15O;B#o\xf0\x0e\x91 AI`w\x84\xf8\xf7\xadp\xd3\x0e....omissis

decomp data  b'{"messageMetaData":{"eventType":"LOCATION","messageType":"LOCATION_CLIENT_CENTRIC"},"data":{"ownerId":136502,"observations":[{"clientMac":"A89CED7E3B77",....omissis